# Tag management in App Engine Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing, tags, google-cloud-datastore

**Situation:** I'm planning to provide tag support to a set of objects in Datastore. The tags are meant to be searchable, so they must be indexed. My biggest concern is exploding indexes of course.

Would the following scenario potentially lead to exploding indexes:

- Datastore object Foo has an a tags attribute. Generally Foo would have at most 5-8 tags assigned to it.
- At most there is a known set of 80 tags. Foo will only be contain tags within  this set of 80.

  - There will exist about 100,000 foo elements within the data store at any given time.

**Question 1:** I'm mostly trying to fully understand how explosive our tag index might become. Would the above scenario lead to a very explosive index?

**Question 2:** Are there any recommended best practices to managing Tags in Datastore?

---

**Follow Up - Data Lookup via a Relational Index**
As an alternate to tags within an object, what about having a separate tag store object that looks something like this:

```
TagStore {
    private String tag;
    private String fooId;
    private long timestamp; 
}
```

Using the above, consider the the following scenario: we want to associate an instance of object Foo with the tags "cat", "horse", and "funicular". In this case we create and save Foo instance AND create and save 3 separate TagStore instances, each TagStore instance has its own tag and points to Foo via its fooId.

***Getting Foo by TagStore:***
For retrieval of recent Foo instances tagged "cat" you would first select:

```
SELECT TagStore WHERE tag=cat ORDER BY timestamp;
```

THEN, with the GQL response you can then get the foo set via

```
SELECT Foo where Foo.id IN ({Set of foo id's here})
```

I would think this is a more structured approach as you are defining exactly how you want the lookup to be managed and you are not cluttering the Foo object with any sort of tag complexity. Of course if each Foo object has 8 tags, there must exist 8 related TagStore objects.

Does this seem like a sensible alternative to simply tagging Foo itself? Is this too much overhead?

Comment: Checking if I got the question right: you have a total of 80 tags. You have a Foo object which will be tagged by a subset of all tags, having mostly between 5-8 tags per Foo object?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Nick.

And if you are using repeated property as your tags, 5-8 tags are already efficient enough. Just avoid storing like 100+ tags in one property/entity.
100,000 entities is okay, because datastore uses indexes.

And I have used that approach on many projects already and did not have any problems. So you are good to go.

Comment: I agree with this. He also answered both of your question

Comment: Hi @user2024780, thanks for this reply. What are your thoughts on my update (see "Follow Up - Data Lookup via a Relational Index ") to the question?

Good to know you haven't run into any issues.

Comment: @AtariPete, I haven't implemented something like that before in NDB, but it looks okay for me because they almost like have the same underlying query structure if Tags was one with Foo. The only difference is that you have 2 queries. And you have more TagStore entities. In this case you will have more ops, for writing and not much on read ops (read more on [Cost for Datastore Calls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls) if this is a concern) ), but other than that, if im not mistaken, i think it is okay.

Comment: on second thought, maybe you have more read ops too because you have to iterate though TagStore fetched entities. But if it doesnt matter and the tructure matters most for you, then it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

The specific situation you described will be fine. Indexes will begin to get out of control when you start filtering or ordering on other properties.

For example, find all foo that were created by a specific user ordered by creation date ascending will require a new index, and if you want descending, another index.

Consider the basic search and sort permutations you will need to offer - you should assume each one will require its own index. So if it's just search with a single ordering you're good to go.

If you want the user to slice and dice (I.e. A standard advanced search UI) you should look into an alternative. The only viable appengine hosted solutions are the search service and cloudsql. After that you're looking at something like a hosted elastic search on GCE or similar alternative.

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for this reply. What are your thoughts on my edit update (see "Follow Up - Data Lookup via a Relational Index ") to the question?

Ideally we'll prob want to search by: tag, datetime, and another internal classification (a like type="animal").